# Need twilio response while call is in-progress

Tags: twilio

I am giving a call facilty in my app using TWILIO. I am using javascript and php to accomplish this. I am using the followinmg code and my call is working properly But I want to show call duration on the page while call is in progress. I am unable to get the record/details of the call. can you please help me . Thanks in advance :

```
 <?php
 include 'Services/Twilio/Capability .php';
 // put your Twilio API credentials here
 $accountSid = 'AC';
 $authToken = 'ce';
// put your Twilio Application Sid here
$appSid = 'AP';
$capability = new Services_Twilio_Capability($accountSid, $authToken);
$capability->allowClientOutgoing($appSid);
$capability->allowClientIncoming('Harry');
$token = $capability->generateToken();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Client</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.1/twilio.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link href="http://static0.twilio.com/packages/quickstart/client.css"
type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
Twilio.Device.setup("<?php echo $token; ?>");
Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
$("#log").text("Ready");
});
Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
$("#log").text("Error: " + error.message);
});
Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
$("#log").text("Successfully established call");
});
Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
$("#log").text("Call ended");       
Twilio.Device.parameters();
});
Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
$("#log").text("Incoming connection from " + conn.parameters.From);
// accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
conn.accept();
});  
function call() { 
// get the phone number to connect the call to
params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val()};
Twilio.Device.connect(params);
}
function hangup() {
Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="call" onclick="call();">
Call
</button>
<button class="hangup" onclick="hangup();">
Hangup
</button>
<input type="text" id="number" name="number"
placeholder="Enter a phone number to call"/>
<div id="log">Loading pigeons...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a function every 1000 milliseconds or so ([using setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)) when the [`Twilio.Device.connect`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#connect) callback function is called (this happens when the VoIP call starts).  Every time the function in setInterval fires, update an HTML element on the page with the new time value.  Use the `Twilio.Device.disconnect` callback function to stop the timer when the call ends and update the UI as necessary.